# Using clipboard with Phonegap in Android

Tags: android, cordova, clipboard, phonegap-plugins

How could I copy text to clipboard with PhoneGap? I found [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ClipboardManager) plugin, but it seems to be outdated.

I tried to create my own plugin, but I get this error:
`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

I found some answers fixing that error, but I'm not too experienced with Java, and I couldn't fix the code by myself. You can view my code from [here](http://pastebin.com/1eydgdL7), it is just modified version of the ClipboardManager plugin.

I'm using Cordova (PhoneGap) version 1.9.0, and I'm also using jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run UI code in a thread different than the UI thread. You'll need to wrap your clip board code in a runable like this:

```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           // Do clipboard stuff here.
        }
    };
    this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
```

Comment: Thank you Simon! This **again** fixed my problem! If anyone else wonders, where you have to put that code, just put that to the execute (that was it for me), and then find the places where you use the Android clipboard. Then put your original code inside that run().